# PowerBi - error reading DateTime field from excel

Tags: powerbi, servicenow

I have PowerBi dashboard that reads data from an excel sheet.

The excel is extracted from my email and put in sharepoint location using power automate.

Unfortunately, when the excel is created, the created column (DateTime) is not wide enough and shows the Datetime as hashtags and PowerBi cannot read properly from that column.
[image]

If I manually adjust the column and get PowerBi to read from it, it will refresh the data with no problems.

Has anyone experienced these issues and any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure the formatting on that column is Date?

Comment: your right. Its not a Date. Its 'Custom' - dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss